# SQL Get Column in a single row that is not zero

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Say I have a table like this:

Table name: Test

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
--------------------------
a    | 0    | 0    | 1
```

Is it possible to retrieve the row, and just the column that is not zero, without having to list each column separately?

Is there a simple way to just select the row that has a value of 1? only 1 column will have a integer value of 1 on each row.

I am trying to get the column name of this one row that is not zero. The columns in this table will grow, so I dont want to have to list each column name in my sql statement. Im using SQLite.

Comment: Not necessarily efficient, but you could do a query for each field in the schema.

Comment: Yea, I know what you mean, but I am gonna be adding more columns to this table, so Im trying to avoid that.

Comment: which SQL... You have both MySQL and SQLite, let alone SQL (SQL-server, Oracle, and many others)

Comment: Sorry its in SQLite, I will edit and add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relational databases are intended to do operations in rows, not in columns.. so columns operations are very inefficient. Maybe you are using wrong approach to your problem. consider this: suppose that you found a way to solve your situation, what will happen if more than one "1" is present? what if no "1" is present?

then i suppose you want also the column name that has "1" value, so where do you manage to store it in result?

I Strongly suggest you to store that info in  another table, so you can quickly achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree with @kappa, seems a very strange thing to try and do.  Perhaps you need a table with 2 columns - name and value or something and just select the ones that where value > 0.

Comment: yea, I see what you mean, thats a great idea

Answer (score 0):

Does something like achieve what you are looking for?

```
create table Test
(
    col1 nvarchar(100),
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    col4 int
)
insert into Test  values('a', 1, 0, 0)
insert into Test values('b', 0, 2, 0)
insert into Test values('c', 0, 0, 3)

select col1, val = case
    when col2 > 0 then col2
    when col3 > 0 then col3
    when col4 > 0 then col4
    end
from test
```

Comment: actually Im looking for something more like this: select (col2, col3, col4) where col1=value and col2 != 0 and col3 != 0 and col4 != 0; but I would would like do it without having to write down each column name. I just want to the one column that is not zero in col2, col3, col4

Comment: @kappa yes, but you could dynamically create that sql if necessary.

Comment: @bryansammon then you are out of luck as that's not possible (without dynamically creating the sql anyway)

Comment: If sqlite supports something like oracle's "execute immediate" you can  iterate over information schema and doing your checks... lot of queries to get so simple data. I suggest again to store that information by rows in another table.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is loop through each column and determine if the value is one in that column for each row.  Here is an example you can modify for your environment:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

You will need to tweak it as well in order for it to work with SQLite.  Here is a quote I found from a guy who did just that:

> I ended up doing it with couple of loops by, first, pulling the array of table names from sqlite_master table and then another loop to cycle through each column name, which I pull out of dbCursor.description. 
>   http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=219441

This is going to be a messy process but it might serve your needs.  If you don't want to get too complicated, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 'Col1' AS Column
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col2' AS Column
FROM Table
WHERE Col2 = 1
etc.
```

That is a lot of manual work and it will need to be updated as you change columns but it may be simpler for you.

Comment: that probably do the work.. but are you sure it's a thing worth doing it?

Comment: @kappa - Well, it is ugly and it won't win any speed awards but that is really up to the person who needs it.  Everything depends on the circumstances.  I wouldn't design a database with this plan in mind, but if I had to work with an existing system and I needed that report, I would definitely consider it.